# Nomenclature double interline... why?

Tags: spacing, line-spacing, nomenclature

unfortunately I have some issue with the nomenclature. It works fine but I have double interline between each nomenclature. Could you help me please? How to get a normal nomenclature?
I attaching the preamble of my article and the nomenclature. Thanks in advance!

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,titlepage]{book} 
\usepackage[paperwidth=165mm, paperheight=238mm, left=2.5cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\newcommand*{\Resize}[2]{\resizebox{#1}{!}{$#2$}}%

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{empheq, nccmath}
%\usepackage{amsmath}
 %  \usepackage[overload]{empheq}

 \usepackage{empheq, nccmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{showframe} \usepackage{cases}

\DeclareFontFamily{U}{mathx}{\hyphenchar\font45}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{mathx}{m}{n}{
<-6> mathx5 <6-7> mathx6 <7-8> mathx7
<8-9> mathx8 <9-10> mathx9
<10-12> mathx10 <12-> mathx12
}{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{mathx}{U}{mathx}{m}{n}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{U}{mathx}{m}{n}

\DeclareMathAccent{\widebar}{0}{mathx}{"73}  


\usepackage{subfloat}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{showframe} 

\usepackage{fontspec}

\usepackage{lineno}
%\linenumbers
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1} 
\setlength{\parindent}{4em}

\pagenumbering{arabic}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\cfoot{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}

%\bibliographystyle{plain}
\renewcommand\thesection{\arabic{section}}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
\usepackage{epstopdf}

\usepackage{nomencl}
\makenomenclature
\usepackage{cases}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\renewcommand\nomgroup[1]{%
  \item[\bfseries
  \ifstrequal{#1}{A}{Symbols}{%
  \ifstrequal{#1}{B}{Subscripts}{%
  \ifstrequal{#1}{C}{Superscripts}{%
  \ifstrequal{#1}{D}{Acronyms{}}}}}%
]}

 % This will add the units
%----------------------------------------------
\newcommand{\nomunit}[1]{%
\renewcommand{\nomentryend}{\hspace*{\fill}#1}}
%----------------------------------------------

\begin{document}

\setlength{\baselineskip}{13pt}
\setmainfont{Georgia}

\setcounter{section}{2}
\setcounter{figure}{1}

\printnomenclature[0.75in]

...
...
...
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Your document uses fontspec so can't be used with pdftex so `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` should be deleted  I couldn't get it to produce the output shown but `\setlength{\parindent}{4em}` looks suspicious, what happens if you remove that?

Comment: May you add some nomenclature entries to your example code?

Comment: Hi \setlength{\parindent}{4em} works well, it sets the indent at each new paragraph. I deleted usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} but nothing happens. The example, I do not know why but it looks that it does not work. It works only with the entire document.

Comment: sorry I misread it for \parskip (that's what happens if you don't provide a usable example and rely on people debugging by eyeballing the code:-) If you delete inputenc something will happen: the warning the package gives that it should not be used with xetex will go away. (

Comment: Yes, not it works and the Nomenclature is written well. The problem now how to reduce the font size of the word Nomenclature as the chapter and how to set the word nomenclature on top of the page?

Comment: I made the size of the word Nomenclature as the size of the word chapter with the following command: \renewcommand{\nomname}{\Large Nomenclature}, but I am not able to move the name Nomenclature on the top of the page. Moreover, how I can reduce the font size of the word bibliography and move it on top of the page as well? I am using \begin{thebibliography}{1}

Answer (score 2):

The `nomencl` package sets `\itemsep` to the value of `\nomitemsep` (default 4pt plus 2pt minus 1pt), which is added to `\parsep` (default for `book` class the same as `\nomitemsep`.

If you want tight typesetting, set `\nomitemsep` to the negative of `\parsep`.

The text below `\printnomenclature` is meant to compare the two lists.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{nomencl}

\setlength{\nomitemsep}{-\parsep}

\begin{document}
some text

\printnomenclature[0.75in]

\nomenclature{Q}{Heat loss/power}
\nomenclature{R}{Heat loss/power}
\nomenclature{S}{Heat loss/power}

\noindent Q Heat loss/power\par
\noindent Q Heat loss/power\par
\noindent Q Heat loss/power\par

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You save my life. It works perfectly. The last thing. I would like to have the name Nomenclature on the top of the page and a bit smaller font. Do you know how to do this?

Comment: @chrisis The same style as for chapters is used